# Accessing the value of a particular key in firebase using swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following firebase structure.[Firebase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjlLw.png)

"Users" is the root, with the keys as "Uid". How do i access a particular value of a key for a given "Uid"?

Example: I want to retrieve "mobileno" of a particular user with "Uid" as M5j80aAlmCS3Jcbh0aA3T4Tfzxv1.

Answer (score 2):

To get a user's profile information, use the properties of an instance of FIRUser. For example :

```swift
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
if let user = user {
  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project.
  // Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend server,
  // if you have one. Use getTokenWithCompletion:completion: instead.
  let uid = user.uid
  let email = user.email
  let photoURL = user.photoURL
  // ...
}
```

Refer to the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users?authuser=0) for more info on this.

Answer (score 1):

If it is your uid (or the user's):

```
if let userUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
    %firebaseReferenceVariable%.child("Users/\(userUID)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in 
        if snapshot.value is NSNull{
             //handles errors
             return
        }
        else{
             if let selectedUser = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary //OR [Stirng: Any]{
                 let mobileno = selectedUser["mobileno"] as! String
                 //Do something with mobileno
             }
        }

   })
}
```

You can replace the variable userUID with any string value in the firebase reference call and it will get that user - I would recommend (if you are trying to access these users from your app) to populate a tableView or collectionView (some type of list) with all the users. You can also get all the users and loop through ones you want (let's saying if you had a boolean variable to display this user).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below code I had used Observe Block as I required to get data each time it was updated in a chat App . so you can make use of observe single event to get data and at end remove observer too.

```
   Database.database().reference().child("users").child(your Key value).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

         if snapshot.exists(){

            print(snapshot)

            if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

                //here you can get data as string , int or anyway you want 
                self. mobilenoLabel.text = snapDict["mobileno"] as? String


            }

        }

    })
```